# Converting Matplotlib axis to log only updates labels and not step spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis

I am trying to scale the space on the vertical axis here so it is spaced logarithmically.

After searching the internet the proposed solution was

```
ax.set_zscale('log')
```

After trying that you can see the result below that only the labels where changed and not the actual spacings.

**Before**

**[image: Before]**

**After**

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [documentation for `set_zscale` says](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.set_zscale):

> The axis scale type to apply. **3D axes currently only support linear scales; other scales yield nonsensical results**.

So, the other option is just to take the log of your input z-axis values and label the axis accordingly, e.g.,

```py
import numpy as np

ax.scatter(x, y, np.log10(z))

ax.set_zlabel("log10(GDP Per Capita)")
```